# Move to next _ in the current line with VIM

Tags: vim

I am having a problem when I am looking at words like:

```
my_class_name
```

Pressing w will bring me to the end of the word. I however would like to jump to the next occurence of _.

I am using dt_ to delete till _. Is there something similar with a jump command?

Comment: I think you'll probably be interested in this script for a more robust solution.  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In normal mode use <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> with no modifier to jump to the character before the next `_`. Use <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> to jump directly to that character. Or use <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> to search for occurrences across all lines (which will automatically jump to the first match).

Comment: when `f` `_` is used, we can use `;` to repeat the last search (doesn't work with `t`).

Comment: Also, when `/` is used, then use `n` to jump to subsequent occurrences.

Comment: Actually, with a recent enough vim `;` can also repeat t commands.

Answer (score 5):

In command mode <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> will do the trick.

Comment: +1 for being faster than me. I just wanted to add the other options.